# Dual Plotting X-Axis via Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have 2 datasets (df3 and df4 which respectively hold information for total head and efficiency) with a common independent variable (flow rate).

I am looking to plot both of them in the same graph but the dependent variables have different y-axes. I initially used `lmplot()` for the polynomial order functionality but this was unsuccessful in having both plots appear in one window. I would like assistance with combining both my scatter plot and regression plots into one plot which shows the overlap between the datasets.

I have used the following approach to generate my charts:

```
ax2.scatter(df3['Flow_Rate_(KG/S)'], df2['Efficiency_%'], color='pink')
ax2.scatter(df4['Flow_Rate_(KG/S)'], df4['Total Head'], color='teal')
plt.show()
```

The reason why it is important for the lines to be plotted against each other is that to monitor pump performance, we need to have both the total head (M) and efficiency % of the pump to understand the relationship and subsequent degradation of performance.

The only other way I could think of is to write the polynomial functions as equations to be put into arguments in the plot function and have them drawn out as such. I haven't yet tried this but thought I'd ask if there are any other alternatives before I head down this pathway.

[image: Scatter Plot]

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - Are you saying it is possible to get the two polynomials I created in seaborn, in one plot? I was just wondering if there are any other options besides the one I had suggested. Otherwise, I'll try the equation approach. The only problem with that is that solution would require a fixed equation when in reality, the equation may change.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - thank you for the tips on how to improve my question. I have duly edited it as such. I hope it makes what I'm after a bit clearer :).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I have tried the approach you have provided but for some reason my axis does not seem to recognise the 'efficiency' y-axis but only the Total Head. Would you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I have solved my earlier problem by setting the y-axis via ax2.set_ylim(0,1). Thanks for your help earlier!

Comment: Yes, I think `regplot` somehow prevents the figure from autoscaling. Setting the `ylim` manually is an easy solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase the problem: You have two datasets with common independent values, but different dependent values (f(x), g(x) respectively). You want to plot them both in the same graph, however the dependent values have totally different ranges. Therefore you want to have two different y axes, one for each dataset. The data should be plotted as a scatter plot and a regression line should be shown for each of them; you are more interested in seeing the regression line than knowing or calculating the regression curve itself. Hence you tried to use seaborn `lmplot`, but you were unsuccessful to get both datasets into the same graph.

In case the above is the problem you want to solve, the answer could be the following.

`lmplot` essentially plots a `regplot` to an axes grid. Because you don't need that axes grid here, using a `regplot` may make more sense. You may then create an axes and a twin axes and plot one regplot to each of them.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.sort(np.random.rand(30)),
                    "f": np.sort(np.random.rayleigh(size=30))})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.sort(np.random.rand(30)),
                    "g": 500-0.1*np.sort(np.random.rayleigh(20,size=30))**2})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.regplot(x="x", y="f", data=df1, order=2, ax=ax)
sns.regplot(x="x", y="g", data=df2, order=2, ax=ax2)


ax2.legend(handles=[a.lines[0] for a in [ax,ax2]], 
           labels=["f", "g"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: From the above you also see how a [mcve] could look like which you could use for a question like this.

Comment: Incredible - that is exactly what I am after! Thank you so much! I will take note of how to improve my question for next time. I had no idea you could use the ax=ax argument in the .regplot. I didn't even know you could use order=2 with that function - thanks for teaching me something new! I'm very appreciative!

Comment: It often helps to just read [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html), where it says *"This function combines regplot() and FacetGrid. [...] Understanding the difference between regplot() and lmplot() can be a bit tricky. In fact, they are closely related, as lmplot() uses regplot() internally and takes most of its parameters.However, regplot() is an axes-level function, so it draws directly onto an axes (either the currently active axes or the one provided by the ax parameter), while lmplot() is a figure-level function [..]"*